# Is "title" a valid attribute for the html image tag?

Tags: html, image, title

I do not see `title` listed as an attribute for html `<img>` on [sitepoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/img) or [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img), or even on [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/img.html), yet it is widely used, and compatible in most browsers. I want to know if this is indeed a valid img attribute?

If so, why is it not listed on those sites. If not, why is it so widely used, and should I use it or no?

Comment: Yes. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html

Comment: @j08691, congrats on your "gr8" reputation score. :)

Comment: It's not listed on the above sites because it applies to all elements. It's global. Same reason they don't list `id` and `class`.

Comment: @JonathanM - I know, time to buy some scratch off lottery tix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `title` is a global attribute: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-title-attribute

> The title attribute represents advisory information for the element, such as would be appropriate for a tooltip. On a link, this could be the title or a description of the target resource; on an image, it could be the image credit or a description of the image; on a paragraph, it could be a footnote or commentary on the text; on a citation, it could be furtherinformation about the source; on interactive content, it could be a label for, or instructions for, use of the element; and so forth. The value is text.

Attributes are listed in the specification:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element

> Content attributes:
>
> - Global attributes
> - alt - Replacement text for use when images are not available
> - src - Address of the resource
> - crossorigin - How the element handles crossorigin requests
> - usemap - Name of image map to use
> - ismap - Whether the image is a server-side image map
> - width - Horizontal dimension
> - height - Vertical dimension

Comment: Other globals include `id`, `class` and `style` (see: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#global-attributes)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, look here for example:

< http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-title-attribute>

Comment: You cited a page that's over eleven years old?

Answer (score 0):

**title** is a global attribute, which means that it can be used on *any* element.

Answer (score 0):

The `title` attribute is more like *meta* information on various types of HTML tags. There is no harm in not having it, but if present, it can be used in anyway you want either in Javascript/ any DOM parsing.

Check the usage of it this [W3 schools - TryIt!](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_title) with the ID *myAbbr*